# Azure web app file permissions

Tags: azure

I created an Azure web app.

I have in my web app a C# command to write to c:\MyDirectory

unfortunately my app does not allow me to write there.  How would I set this file permissions in Azure?

Comment: [This SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20615289/310446) is relevant.

Answer (score 1):

Azure webapp (web role) will give you write access only to the root folder of your website and below.

Alternatives:

1. Write files to Server.MapPath("~/") or anywhere inside it.
2. Use blob storage (**recommended**): http://azure.microsoft.com/pt-br/documentation/articles/storage-dotnet-how-to-use-blobs/